# App crash when run to sd_setImageWithURL method

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

This crash only happen on iPad 4,I have tried with some other device, all of

them run ok, Has anyone has this happen to them?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it happen all the time? How about set it to NULL. `static dispatch_once_t once = NULL;`

Comment: Yes, it happen all the time when i use my iPad 4 to test.

static dispatch_once_t once = NULL not work for me.